# Cannot read property of 'get' of undefined, express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Apologies for the title in advance, I really do not know how to summarize this.

I'm getting the following error while trying to run my Express app

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at authHandler (file:///api/src/authUtil.mjs:34:19)
    at file:////api/src/routes/application.mjs:6:12
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:96:12)
```

`authHandler` is a function that looks something like this:

```
export function authHandler (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.get('Authorization')
  //shortened
  next()
}
```

It's being called in `application.mjs` from an Express router like this:

`router.use(authHandler())` (yes, it's imported)

But, for some reason, `req` is showing as undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, did you pass `req, res` to the function? As in, `authHandler(req,res..)`?

Comment: `router.use(authHandler())` seems wrong if `router` is what I think it is, consider trying `app.use(authHandler())` if `app` is your express instance

Comment: @SumanKundu [`express.Router` also has a `.use` method](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use)

Comment: Ohh yes, the answer makes sense, you were calling that function immediately with no argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling your handler and registering its result to the router.
What you actually want to do is register the handler itself: `router.use(authHandler)`

Edit: The reason for your error is that you call `authHandler` without any arguments. Anyway, you don't need to call it at all.

Comment: Moreover, because it's getting called without arguments, `req` _is_ undefined, ultimately resulting in the error.

Comment: You're right. I'll update my answer because that makes it technically wrong.